# UILocalNotification versus EKReminder with EKAlarm

Tags: ios

Can someone me explain the difference and when to use UILocalNotification versus EKReminder with EKAlarm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From UILocalNotification you can send a in-app notification. EKReminder is using when you want to access the os reminder DB. If you set a EKReminder even if the app is beeing deleted, you will get the notification.

Comment: Meaning notificationa are entirely managed by my app, and they neither appear in the calendar app nor the reminder app?

Comment: If you added notification using EKReminder it will appear on the reminder app. if you want to appear it only from your app, you can use local notifications.